# Spring html view response

Tags: java, spring

I started learning Spring framework, and I have trouble with redirecting to pages. I use pure html, because I want my front-end to be more independent (unlike jsp). I use .xml config that looks like this:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="controllers"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
</bean> 

<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
```

Some basic controllers works fine, I can go to page if I use GET method(and type in browser sth like this: http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/home):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/", "/home"})
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String goHome() {
        System.out.println("HOME CONTROLLER");
        return "resources/static/home"; // <-- name of the view (.html)
        //return "home";
    }
}
```

However if I want to redirect user after he uses registration form and post method i get blank page with text: "resources/static/home".

Controller looks like this:

```
 @Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegisterController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RegisterController.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String goRegister() { // this method works fine
        return "resources/static/register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String doRegister(User user) { // this does not send user back to home page
        logger.info("register new user request");
        System.out.println(user.toString());

        // TODO validation of user

        return "resources/static/home";
    }
}
```

User class is properly set with values from the form, but instead of redirecting back to the home page, I get a blank html with text. I tried to use:

```
return "redirect:resources/static/home";
```

but it did not work either.

Register file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Register your account here.</h1>

    <form method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" /><br>
    Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" /><br>
    e-mail: <input type="email" name="email" /><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br>
    Retype password: <input type="password" name="repassword" /><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I can not understand the logic of this. Why GET method is able to return view, while POST is not.

Edit:
I forgot to mention, that previously when I used .jsp pages, almost the same code worked fine and of course I had different .xml config and controllers only returned view name, example:
 `return "home";`

Edit2:
This is the source:
https://github.com/robson021/InvoiceWriterFinal

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@ResponseBody` from the `doRegister` method. This annotation is sending your string as response to the http call.

When you do not have the annotation the view resolvers you have registered are processing the string and rendering the corresponding html.

Comment: After I have done it, I got: "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported"

Comment: Should have worked already as you said it works, just not producing right page. Try `@RequestBody User user`